# Removing duplicate values from a PowerShell array

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can I remove duplicates from a PowerShell array?

```
$a = @(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,0,0)
```

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (whose alias is `select`) with the `-Unique` switch; e.g.:

```
$a = @(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,0,0)
$a = $a | select -Unique
```

Comment: That was too easy :-(. In PowerShell 2 you can also use `Get-Unique` (or `gu`) if your array is already sorted.

Comment: Johannes, Get-Unique is available in v1 :)

Comment: cool, this works fine, just a Note, if you want to be concise, it could be shortened even to `-u`. `select -u` I would use this on a command line, but written in a code, it's suggested to use the full PS wording: `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: This only works with single digit? For a large list of array it seems not to works.

Comment: This isn't working correctly for me, it's only keeping the one value that has a duplicate, almost like it's creating a list of duplicates.

Comment: Just to note, select -unique doesn't account for case sensitivity so this won't work in a lot of cases.  sort -unique is the correct method, (although you'll end up with a sorted array)

Answer (score 101):

Another option is to use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) (whose alias is `sort`, but only on Windows) with the 
`-Unique` switch, which combines sorting with removal of duplicates:

```
$a | sort -unique
```

Comment: This also solves my next problem which is how do I sort it.  Thanks!

Comment: This one also looks a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Note that this does not preserve order of the elements, e.g. `@("B", "a", "A") | sort -unique` produces `A B`.

Comment: this is the better answer.  select -unique doesn't account for case sensitivity

Answer (score 26):

In case you want to be fully bombproof, this is what I would advise:

```
@('Apples', 'Apples ', 'APPLES', 'Banana') | 
    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={$_.Trim()}} -Unique
```

**Output:**

```
Apples
Banana
```

This uses the `Property` parameter to first `Trim()` the strings, so extra spaces are removed and then selects only the `-Unique` values.

More info on `Sort-Object`:

```
Get-Help Sort-Object -ShowWindow
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Solved my issue, `Get-Unique` didn't work because spaces

Answer (score 10):

```
$a | sort -unique
```

This works with case-insensitive, therefore removing duplicates strings with differing cases. Solved my problem.

```
$ServerList = @(
    "FS3",
    "HQ2",
    "hq2"
) | sort -Unique

$ServerList
```

The above outputs:

```
FS3
HQ2
```

Comment: this also works well for arrays with multiple members

Answer (score 9):

This is how you get unique from an array with two or more properties. The sort is vital and the key to getting it to work correctly. Otherwise you just get one item returned.

**PowerShell Script:**

```
$objects = @(
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "1"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "2"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "3"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "4"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "5"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "1"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "2"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "3"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "4"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "5"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "1"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "2"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "3"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "4"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "5"; MachineName = "1" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "1"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "2"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "3"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "4"; MachineName = "2" }
    [PSCustomObject] @{ Message = "5"; MachineName = "2" }
)

Write-Host "Sorted on both properties with -Unique" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$objects | Sort-Object -Property Message,MachineName -Unique | Out-Host

Write-Host "Sorted on just Message with -Unique" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$objects | Sort-Object -Property Message -Unique | Out-Host

Write-Host "Sorted on just MachineName with -Unique" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$objects | Sort-Object -Property MachineName -Unique | Out-Host
```

**Output:**

```
Sorted on both properties with -Unique

Message MachineName
------- -----------
1       1          
1       2          
2       1          
2       2          
3       1          
3       2          
4       1          
4       2          
5       1          
5       2          


Sorted on just Message with -Unique

Message MachineName
------- -----------
1       1          
2       1          
3       1          
4       1          
5       2          


Sorted on just MachineName with -Unique

Message MachineName
------- -----------
1       1          
3       2
```

**Source:**
https://powershell.org/forums/topic/need-to-unique-based-on-multiple-properties/

Comment: For loops that you might not know the header for (ie. parsing automatically some csv data) - use 

Sort-Object * -unique

Answer (score 4):

If the list is sorted, you can use the [Get-Unique](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113335) cmdlet:

```
 $a | Get-Unique
```

Comment: It requires the list to be sorted on beforehand

Answer (score 3):

With my method you can completely remove duplicate values, leaving you with values from the array that only had a count of 1. It was not clear if this is what the OP actually wanted however I was unable to find an example of this solution online so here it is.

```
$array=@'
Bananna
Apple
Carrot
Pear
Apricot
Pear
Bananna
'@ -split '\r\n'

($array | Group-Object -NoElement | ?{$_.count -eq 1}).Name
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but there's a big flaw with it.  if there are multiple elements with the same name, all those elements are lost, it should instead keep one of them.  This fixed it: `($properties | Group-Object -NoElement).Name | Get-Unique`

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're using `SORT -UNIQUE`, `SELECT -UNIQUE` or `GET-UNIQUE` from Powershell 2.0 to 5.1, all the examples given are on single Column arrays.  I have yet to get this to function across Arrays with multiple Columns to *REMOVE* Duplicate Rows to leave single occurrences of a Row across said Columns, or develop an alternative script solution.  Instead these cmdlets have only returned Rows in an Array that occurred ONCE with singular occurrence and dumped everything that had a duplicate.  Typically I have to Remove Duplicates manually from the final CSV output in Excel to finish the report, but sometimes I would like to continue working with said data within Powershell after removing the duplicates.

Comment: this is where the Where-Object comes in handy. You first narrow the list down by using the right where clause, then pipe it to a sort-object, select one or more columsn to sort, and give the sort-object a -unique.

Comment: @Christopher, please see my post to fix your problem. Consider removing this answer to clean up the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To get unique items from an array and preserve their order, you can use .NET HashSet:

```
$Array = @(1, 3, 1, 2)
$Set = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]' -ArgumentList (,[int[]]$Array)

# PS> $Set
# 1
# 3
# 2
```

Works best with string arrays that contain both uppercase and lowercase items where you need to preserve first occurrence of each item in case-insensitive manner:

```
$Array = @("B", "b", "a", "A")
$Set = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]' -ArgumentList ([string[]]$Array, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

# PS> $Set
# B
# a
```

Works as expected with other types.

Shortened syntax, compatible with PowerShell 5.1 and newer:

```
$Array = @("B", "b", "a", "A")
$Set = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$Array, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

$Array = @(1, 3, 1, 2)
$Set = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new([int[]]$Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the provided answers give buggy results.
`select -Unqiue` is not case sensitive.
`sort -Unique` gives you sorted results, which you might want in the original order.

Will gave a great answer, but it's flawed as it discards all duplicate results but forgets to keep one of them.

This is a version I created that seems to work perfectly.  It gives unique results back and retains the original sort order.

`($properties | Group-Object -NoElement).Name | Get-Unique`

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = @('D:/', 'two', 'three')
$s = "D:/"
$null -ne ($a | ? { $s -match $_ })  # Returns $true
```

another solution can be used here , u're welcome

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
$data = Get-Content $file |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Property id, name, streetName1, zipCode, city |
    Sort-Object -Property id -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

For an "array" aka string with multiple lines, you can use this:

```
$a.Split("`n") | select -unique | sort
```