# Remove duplicates from beginning of array

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates

Similar to [Removing duplicate values from a PowerShell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391853/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-powershell-array) I want to remove elements from an array. The issue is, I actively work with the end of the array so I want to keep the last instance of a duplicate. `| select -uniq` removes duplicates that come after it in an array.

Example (Taken from above link modified a little bit):

`$a = @(1,2,5,3,0,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,0)
$a = $a | select -uniq`

Output for $a:

1,2,5,3,0,4,6,7,8,9

But the desired output I'm looking for:

1,3,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,0

Essentially I want leave the last instance of a duplicate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to reverse the array so that `select -unique` is effectively working in reverse, then reverse the result to normalize it.

```
$a = @(1,2,5,3,0,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,0)
[array]::Reverse($a)
$a = $a | select -unique
[array]::Reverse($a)
$a -join ','
1,3,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,0
```

Comment: Or `($a[$a.length..0] | select -uniq)[$a.length..0]` for quick runs in the console.