# Find next number in a sequence

Tags: powershell

I'm working to find the next available number in a set of numbers and have trouble.

My dataset is an array of strings that is then converted to an array of integers.  The original dataset may have duplicate numbers.

When I try and find the next available number, the duplicates seem to cause issues yielding bad results

```
$dataset = "0001","0002","0004","0006","2","5"

#Convert our strings to integers
[array]$Used = foreach($number in $dataset) {
   try {
         [int]::parse($number)
   } catch {
         Invoke-Expression -Command $number;
   }
}

[array]::sort($Used)

$range = 1..10
$Available = compare $range $Used -PassThru
```

My results are:

```
$Dataset = 
0001
0002
0004
0006
2
5

$Used = 
1
2
2
4
5
6
```

Noticed that `$Used` (which is sorted) shows that `2` is a duplicate:

```
$Available = 
2
3
7
8
9
10
```

Finally `$Available` lists `2` as an available number which is wrong. `2` is actually used twice and the correct answer should be `3`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$Available = compare $range $used -PassThru | where SideIndicator -eq '<='`

Comment: Or `$Available = Compare-object $range ($used|Sort-Object -Unique) -PassThru`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered before: [Removing duplicate values from a PowerShell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391853/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-powershell-array)

Lots of great answer options, but basically:

`$Used = $Used | select -uniq`
or another option
`$Used | sort -uniq`

Answer (score 1):

Converting your strings to numbers can be done with a simple *cast*:

```
$dataset = "0001","0002","0004","0006","2","5"

$numbers = [int[]] $dataset
```

To sort these numbers and eliminate duplicates:

```
$uniqueSortedNumbers = $numbers | Sort-Object -Unique
```

To find the first available number inside the resulting list, or possibly the next higher number:

```
# Find the first gap in the list of sorted numbers, if any.
$nextAvailableNumber = 
  Compare-Object -PassThru $uniqueSortedNumbers (1..($uniqueSortedNumbers[-1])) |
    Select-Object -First 1 

# If there was no gap, use the highest number + 1
if ($null -eq $nextAvailableNumber) { 
  $nextAvailableNumber = $uniqueSortedNumbers[-1] + 1
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`Compare-Object` lists objects that are unique to *either* collection.

By having duplicates in `$used`, the duplicates are also reported as unique, because `$range` has no duplicate counterparts.

With `-PassThru`, the unique values are passed through without (obvious) distinction as to which input collection they're unique to, so you end up with a mix of numbers unique to either collection, comprising *both* the numbers unique to `$range` *and* the duplicates, which explains your symptom.

By eliminating duplicates from `$used` beforehand, the problem is avoided, because all unique values are then guaranteed to be from `$range` only.

Answer (score 0):

the `Compare-Object` cmdlet always confuses me [*blush*], so i avoided it entirely. [*grin*] this works by ...

- converting the data set `[string]` items into `[int]` items
- removing the dupes
- filtering for target range numbers that are NOT in the used numbers list

here's the code ...

```
$DataSet = '0001','0002','0004','0006','2','5'
$UsedNumbers = $DataSet.
    ForEach({[int]$_}) |
    Sort-Object -Unique

$TargetRange = 1..10

$AvailableNumbers = $TargetRange.
    Where({
        $_ -notin $UsedNumbers
        })

$AvailableNumbers
```

output ...

```
3
7
8
9
10
```